# Change the integer time to date format in Grocery CRUD

Tags: php, codeigniter, iframe, grocery-crud

The view customer action in the example given [link](http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/render)
shows the details regarding the customer.Now among those details I have a field time which shows in int format.

I need to change that int(1443198514) to proper PHP date format(25 Sep 2015 21:58:34).

How to do that. Any relevant help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unix timestamp to date time

```
$timestamp=1333699439;
$today = date("F j, Y, g:i a",$timestamp);                 // March 10, 2001, 5:16 pm
$today = date("m.d.y",$timestamp);                         // 03.10.01
$today = date("j, n, Y",$timestamp);                       // 10, 3, 2001
$today = date("Ymd",$timestamp);                           // 20010310
$today = date('h-i-s, j-m-y, it is w Day',$timestamp);     // 05-16-18, 10-03-01, 1631 1618 6 Satpm01
$today = date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z", $timestamp);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But I want specifically in that CRUD library implementation.

Comment: $crud->callback_column('created', array($this,'date_display'));   This seem to work when Grocery CRUD state='list' but doesnt work when the state='read'

Comment: you should look for where it use  unix time stamp 
for example  **strtotime**